# Get number of rows deleted using checkbox in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

here i want to have no.of coloumns i have checked and deleted in lable

i have used following code to execute my query of deleting multiple values in gridview using checkbox

here is my code and script part

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        grd_bnd();
    }
}
 private void grd_bnd()
{
 SqlConnection con = new        SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checkboxdelete");
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            int rollno = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            //CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checkbox1");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from student where rollno = @rollno ", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@rollno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rollno.ToString();
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
    grd_bnd();
}
}
```

and here is script

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="rollno" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxdelete" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roll No.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblrollno" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("rollno") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Batch">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblbatch" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("batch") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Course">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcourse" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("course") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </gridview>
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Delete Selected" ForeColor="#000066" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#666666"></asp:Label>
```

i wanna get the number of entities deleted in above lable , lable1.

Comment: Is your where clause unique per row? Or will the where return multiple rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a count before your loop

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rows = 0;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checkboxdelete");
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            int rollno = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            //CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checkbox1");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from student where rollno = @rollno ", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@rollno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rollno.ToString();
            con.Open();
            rows += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Can return 0 if no rows were deleted!
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
    grd_bnd();
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Rows affected {0}", rows);
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect since the counter does not return the number of rows affected but the number the `if`-clause in the loop was entered. There are several ways this could fail or return the wrong number.

Comment: Agreed, but if the row is unique then it will only ever delete one row. I understand that the delete can in affect delete zero rows and be misleading as the row didn't exist (potentially). I have updated the answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the return value of [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int numDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**MSDN**: *returns the number of rows affected.*

If you want the total rows use a variable:

```
int totalNumDeleted = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    // ...
    int numDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    totalNumDeleted += numDeleted;
}
Label1.Text = string.Format("{0} students were deleted successfully.", totalNumDeleted);
```

Comment: it is returning 0 but no number

Comment: "It is returning 0 but no number" 0 is  a number. What is the value of `@rollno`, do you have students with those  `rollno` at all? Use the debugger in the loop.

Comment: no 0 is no value in my database  i have 717,718,719 and so on

Comment: @mohit: you're confusing me, i thought that you want to get the number of deleted students and not the `rollNo`.

Comment: sir i have changed as u have given above

Comment: @mohit: sorry, i can't understand. Have you used the debugger to check if the  sql-query and the parameter value are correct and should delete students? Is the `if (checkbox1.Checked)` in the loop entered at all?

Comment: Tim sir and Dr Schizo sir thanks for ur help i have got the answer just did like that ad dr schizo said.   thanks and regards

Comment: @mohit: but i thought that you want to _"Get the number of rows deleted"_ and not the number of times the `if`-clause was entered. Use `ExecuteQuery` since the database is the only source which knows if any students were deleted at all.

Comment: sir i m a begginer and  i was asked just to get the number of rows deleted from gridview in a lable and by that method i got my answer

Comment: @mohit: yes, but if you want to get the number of rows deleted you should ask the database since that is the only reliable source. Consider that no strudents were deleted since you provided a `rollNo` of an already deleted student or that there are multiple students with that `rollNo`. `ExecuteNonQuery` would return the correct result whereas the loop counter just returns always 1 even if none rows were deleted.

Comment: i got u but why u rated me negitive sir

Comment: @mohit: i haven't downvoted you. I have edited your question if that is what you mean.